# How do I boot into an older kernel?

Tags: bootloader

I install new kernel (from launchpad mainline kernel) in my Ubuntu 12.04, in order to test some issues I'm having.

Now, older kernels don't appear in the list at boot, just the new kernel. I can boot from the old kernel changing boot parameters at grub time, but I rather like to have a list entry I can select.

Comment: I would be highly interested how to list and boot previous kernels on Precise as the latest kernel (3.2.0-34) [breaks suspend2RAM if nVidia modules present](http://launchpad.net/bugs/1080530). Booting into 3.2.0-33 would be great until it is fixed.

Comment: Write a bug report to the grub developers. They have lately wiped out a primary functionality of the software.

Comment: @SteveWhite Are you sure this reflects a change in *upstream* GRUB?

Answer (score 1):

Are the older ones not in the Previous kernel list? Assuming you have recovery mode - that would be the third menu entry.

Check that they actually exist in the grub.cfg file

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg  |grep menuentry
```

Answer (score 1):

For Grub (nor Grub2)
edit /boot/grub/menu.lst

```
gksu gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

Search for this line `howmany` . If doesn't exists, add it:
The value holds the amount of kernals are shown on the boot menu.

```
 # howmany=all
```

Update GRUB afterwards

```
sudo update-grub
```

[Tweak Grub](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=818177)

[Tweak Grub 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1287602&)

Comment: This might only work for GRUB 0.99, not GRUB2.